# C++ file container (e.g. zip) for easy access

Tags: c++, zip, archive

I have a lot of small files I need to ship with an application I build and I want to put this files into an archive to make copying and redistributing more easy.
I also really like the idea of having them all in one place so I need to compare the md5 of one file only in case something goes wrong.

I'm thinking about a class which can load the archive and return a list of files within the archive and load a file into memory if I need to access it.

I already searched the Internet for different methods of achieving what I want and found out about zlib and the lzma sdk.
Both didn't really appeal to me because I don't really found out how portable zlib is and I didn't like the lzma sdk as it is just to much and I don't want to blow up the application because of this problem. Another downside with zlib is that I don't have the C/C++ experience (I'm really new to C++) to get everything explained in the manual.

I also have to add that this is a time critical problem. I though some time about implementing a simple format like tar in a way I can easy access the files within my application but I just didn't find the time to do that yet.

So what I'm searching for is a library that allows me to access the files within an archive. I'd be glad if anybody could point me in the right direction here.

Thanks in advance,
Robin.

Edit: I need the archive to be accessed under linux and windows. Sorry I didn't mention that in the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on whether you plan to modify the archive via code after the archive is initially built.

If you don't need to modify it, you can use TAR - it's a handy and simple format. If you want compression, you can implement tar.gz reader or find some library that does this (I believe there are some available, including open-source ones).

If your application needs random access to the data or it needs to modify the archive, then regular TAR or ZIP archives are not good. Virtual file system such as our [SolFS](http://www.eldos.com/solfs/) or CodeBase file system will fit much better: virtual file systems are suited for frequent modifications of the storage, while archives target mainly write-once-read-many usage scenarios.

Comment: Well Zip would be enough but I didn't look into the term VFS at all. I found PhysicsFS and I think that's exactly what I'll be using for my project. Thanks very much for your answere.

Answer (score 3):

For zipping, I've always been partial to [ZipUtils](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/zip_utils.aspx), which makes the process easy and is built on top of the zlib and info-zip libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the link mate but I need it to run on windows and linux. ZipUtils only works on windows.

Comment: @Robin: Can you put that in your question then, please? :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`zlib` is highly portable and very widely used.  if you can't make sense of the C++ interface, there are alternatives for many other languages - see 'Related External Links' [here](http://www.zlib.net/).

Take another look before you search for something different.

Comment: But `zlib` doesn't do what the OP wants which is archiving. It does compression, but it can't understand the .zip file format by itself.

Comment: Yes, compression is only needed on second though, what I mainly need is to group the hundreds of small files into a single file.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Qt or Windows you can also pack data into the executable's resource area. You would only have to distribute the executable file using this technique. There's a well defined API already written and tested to access that data.

Answer (score 0):

The zlib API is the way to go. Simple and portable. Lookat unzip.h header for APIs that access archive files. It is in C and very easy.

If the files are small, you can dump them into string literals (search for bin2h utility) and include in your project. Then change the code that read the files. If all files are currently read using ifstream class, simply changing it to istringstream class and recompile the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Quazip](http://quazip.sourceforge.net/) - it's quite simple to use. You can use it as a stream from which you read the compressed file on the fly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I wouldn't want to bloat a console application with qt dependencies.